# Инициализация многомерного массива констант - куча ворнингов.

Tags: c, массивы, avr-gcc, const, atmel-studio

Код таков:

```
const byte SequenceArray[]  =   {{0,2,1,2,0,5,3},{0,2,1,2,4,6,6}};
volatile int B = SequenceArray[1][1];;
```

Запускаю отладку, смотрю значение В, там нули.

И куча ворнингов

Много - (near initialization for 'SequenceArray[0]') [enabled by default]
Два -braces around scalar initializer [enabled by default]
Много - excess elements in scalar initializer [enabled by default]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ни первая, ни вторая строка не являются легальными в языке С.

Такая инициализация

```
const byte SequenceArray[]  =   {{0,2,1,2,0,5,3},{0,2,1,2,4,6,6}};
```

условно означает, что объявляется массив из двух элементов

```
const byte SequenceArray[2]
```

из который первый инициализируется каким-то странным избыточным набором

```
{0,2,1,2,0,5,3}
```

а второй - набором

```
{0,2,1,2,4,6,6}
```

Это запрещено в С. Некоторые компиляторы с "вялым и распущенным" (по умолчанию) контролем за ошибками, типа GCC, проглатывают такой код просто отбрасывая лишние инициализаторы в каждом наборе. Т.е. ваша первая строчка эквивалентна

```
const byte SequenceArray[2]  = { { 0 }, { 0 } };
```

что эквивалентно

```
const byte SequenceArray[2]  = { 0, 0 };
```

Никакого "многомерного массива" тут нет.

Ваша же вторая строчка совершенно не легальна и никаким уважающим себя компилятором принята не будет. Ваш `SequenceArray` - одномерный массив целых чисел (подразумевая, что `byte` - целый тип)  применить к нему оператор `[]` дважды не получится. Поэтому каким образом вы умудрились "запустить отладку" мне не ясно. Вы что-то выдумываете.

Если вы хотели сделать `SequenceArray` двумерным массивом, то объявлять его надо было именно как двумерный массив

```
const byte SequenceArray[][7]  =  { {0,2,1,2,0,5,3}, {0,2,1,2,4,6,6} };
```

Первый размер можно не указывать, но вот второй указать придется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Поясните почему 1ый индекс можно не указывать, а 2ой обязательно?

Comment: @ReasonX: Потому что таковы требования языка. Тип элемента массива должен быть "завершенным" (complete). Массив неизвестного размера не является "завершенным" типом. Поэтому попытка объявления двумерного массива без указания второго размера - это попытка объявления массива массивов неизвестного размера и нарушение данного требования.

Answer (score 2):

В приведенном примере объявляется одномерный массив, а инициализируется двумерный. Также, в случае с многомерными массивами, надо указывать их размерность. В итоге получаем следующее:

```
const byte SequenceArray[2][7]  =   {{0,2,1,2,0,5,3},{0,2,1,2,4,6,6}};
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Извиняюсь что отнял время своей невнимательностью.

Answer (score 0):

Виноват господа, я пока сам решал, запутался и все ухудшил.

Изначально SequenceArray[][] там, но у меня что то не пошло и я какую то кашу замудрил, пытаясь избавится от ворнингов.

А изначальная проблема была в том, что при отладке, выводятся значения по адресу в RAM, а не ROM. Хотя предается все нормально и B принимает значение 2.

Не знаю как так вышло, наверно потому что 6й час был.

Спасибо за помощь. Всем репы.